# How to show all contacts on Skype

Tags: skype

I enabled a setting that hides my Skype contacts when they are not online. I want to undo this setting - how can I do this on Skype?

Answer (score 1):

Under the "Contacts" dropdown menu you can select "Show All Contacts."